# what will be a good regex to extract pure numbers out of "25 10a 36 10b 30"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i was in need of a regex which will return only 25,36,30 for me from

> 25 10a 36 10b 30

as they are the only pure numbers in the sequence.

I tried this but it did not work for me :

```
(^|[ ])\d+|($|[ ])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This should not be marked community wiki

Comment: I agree. This is a simple, straight question.

Comment: I wonder what's the matter with this "Hi friends" thing that some people seem to have. Maybe it's a cultural thing, but I find it rather disturbing and wish people would just cut it out and get to the point.

Comment: Agree... how is this not a legitimate programming question? Is it marked as community wiki by mistake?

Comment: I guess so. Since only the OP can make that decision, and he has 23 points currently, I believe he simply didn't know what it meant.

Comment: Can you tell me the differnece between a community wiki and a proper question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply globally:

```
(?<=^|\s)\d+(?=\s|$)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) option:

```
\b(\d+)\b
```

but some punctuation characters will be marked as a word boundary so this won't give what you want.

So it looks like you'll have to explicitly look for whitespace:

```
/(^|\s+)(\d+)(\s+|$)/
```

When extracting the number remember to get the second group as the first will only have spaces in it.

Comment: but it matches numbers beginning or ending with spl chars like #25 or 34&

Comment: So it does.  Bother.  Will find something else.

Answer (score 0):

Noticing your multiple regex questions might I suggest some educational reading. [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) has some great tutorials for getting acquainted with RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

`\d+` is all you need. If you're using C#, note the difference between 'Match' and 'Matches' on the `Regex` object. One finds a single match, the other finds multiple non-overlapping matches.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use \b for word boundary.

i guess something like:

```
\b\d+\b
```

Answer (score -1):

This one should do the work:

```
\b\d+\b
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for integers only, use `\b\d+\b`.