# Find pure number from sentence, not alpnanumeric

Tags: java, regex, logic

I'm struggling to make Regex that find only number (pure number e.g. 55) from sentence, not alphanumeric(2nd)

e.g. in sentence "This is your 1st test, and you got 66 marks"
So it should found only "66" not the "1" in 1st.

I've tried `Regex (\d+)`, It found the two numbers "66" and the "1" but **i need only pure number not alpha numeric.**

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/615421/422353

Comment: @ madth3 Well I agree it seems to be, but Question posted there is not well narrated and i literally don't found it during search process. It's by chance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try checking for word boundaries:

```
\b\d+\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this straightforward solution:

```
\s+\d+\s+
```

Comment: This is not as effective as Pavel's answer, because you say that there must be spaces around the number. It'll work in this case, but his pattern is more generic, which is always better :)

Comment: What will happen to `12 ... 34`? (There are no spaces at the begin or the end of the string.)

Comment: you are right, this pattern is not work for numbers at the start/end of the string.